# Initialize onchange event inside a loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to bind an onChange event to 7 dropdowns inside a loop. But when any of dropdown changes, the onChange event for the last one is always executed.

```
$(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        $('select[id$="bodysys' + i + '"]').change(function () {
            if (this.value == "99")
                enabletextbox($('input[id$="bodysys' + i + 'spec"]')[0]);
        });
    }
}
```

How to make onChange work for all elements separately?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called the last one only problem, and is solved using a closure:

```
$(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            $('select[id$="bodysys' + i + '"]').change(function () {
                if (this.value == "99")
                    enabletextbox($('input[id$="bodysys' + i + 'spec"]')[0]);
            });
        })(i);
    }
}
```

It creates a new scope, so when i is changed in the original scope, it will not be changed in the old scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[id*="bodysys"]').each(function (index) {
        $(this).change(function () {
            if ($("option:selected", this).val() == "99")
                enabletext($('input[id$="bodysys' + (index + 1) + 'spec"]')[0]);
        });
    });
```

This way works too.